# Write Postgres "TIME" column from Spark DataFrame via JDBC

Tags: postgresql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, time

I'm reading positional files from a remote folder and transforming it in a Spark DataFrame with Spark Scala. I've a method that converts my line in dataframe rows, taking advantage of the fact that they are positional lines, so I know their schema. This is a small snippet of how I get the values correctly:

```
        val correctValue = field.typ match {
      case StringType => field.value
      case IntegerType =>
        val intRegex = """(\d+)""".r
        val intValue = field.value match {
          case intRegex(field.value) => field.value.toInt
          case _ => null
        }
        intValue
      case DoubleType => field.value.toDouble
```

Later, I create the correct StructType based on field.typ values.

```
def fileSchemaToStructType(fileSchema: FileSchema): StructType = {
  val fields = fileSchema.fields.map { field =>
    StructField(
      field.name,
      field.typ,
      nullable = true
    )
  }
  StructType(fields)
}
```

My issue is that I need to write these files into a PostgreSQL database, and some columns in the PostgreSQL database have a type of "time", pattern like "23:12:22" (hh:mm:ss).

There isn't a StructField type for TimeType, and TimestampType cannot be directly converted to PostgreSQL time, causing errors when I try to write.
I need a workaround that doesn't turn the time into "null" nor modifies the definition of the column in PostgreSQL as I cannot alter the table.
I noticed there is a metadata attribute called "logical_time_type: True" in this GitHub link, but I'm unsure how to use it in my case.

How can I create a column in a DataFrame that is compatible with writing via JDBC to a PostgreSQL database with a column of type "time", starting from a value of type "hh:mm:ss"?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is the format of the datetime field in the file?

Comment: You can get the time part by doing something like that, `df.withColumn("time_only",f.date_format('date_time_field,"HH:mm:ss"))` but there is no datatype in spark which represents time alone.

Comment: There is no format in the file. The file is a positional raw csv, I convert value into rows and I defined the struct type coerent with the postgres table. You think that with this

df.withColumn("time_only",f.date_format('date_time_field,"HH:mm:ss"))

When I write via jdbc, I do not have incompatibility type with "time" column in Postgres?

Comment: It may work, worth trying, while doing insert into on Postgres’s ‘20:00:05’ works in the time field.